# Is there a way to get Google account to sign out after specific time has passed?

Tags: google-account, security, account-management

Is it possible to set a timeout for my Google account to sign out my Google session on any device?

I'm worried about not signing out of all my sessions, especially at the work desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Google itself does not have the feature I'm looking for.

Comment: The closest feature I've seen for it is the Inactive Account Manager.

Answer (score 5):

you have three options:

## **1. browser auto logoff on exit**

By removing your browsing history as soon as you close the browser, this makes sure that no one sees or uses your history if you are sharing the same computer, you have to search **`inetcpl.cpl`** in run menu - **<kbd>WINKEY</kbd>** + **<kbd>R</kbd>** - there you will get Internet properties menu there you have to select **Delete browsing history on Exit** and then **OK**

[image]

## **2. cookie auto logoff by blocking**

You can block most cookies while still allowing them from certain sites. With this exceptions, you can auto log out from Gmail or other webmails.

- on your computer, open Google Chrome
- in the top right, click the **Menu**
- click **Settings** and then **Show advanced settings**
- in the "Privacy" section, click **Content settings**
- under "Cookies," click **Manage exceptions**
- enter the site name you want to allow cookies for. to allow cookies from an entire domain, insert **`[*.]`** before the domain name. for example: **`[*.]google.com`** - this creates an exception for:

  - `mail.google.com`
  - `drive.google.com`
  - `calendar.google.com`
- you can also put an IP address or a web address that doesn't begin with `http` / `https`
- use the menu to choose whether the site can set cookies. If you select **Clear on exit**, its cookies are deleted every time you close your browser and your mail session will end too

## **3. auto logoff extension**

Auto Logout extension automatically logs you out of all logged in accounts upon closure of all browser windows in case you forget to sign out. This extension is recommended for use in shared computers to keep different accounts safe. You just need to add the extension. What this extension does is, it simply logs out from websites once you close Google Chrome. That means you have to log in every time you open up your Chrome browser

**[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-logout/ohlcnddhihadnalofegeookbpglgadhe)**

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out a way to make Chrome sign out on closing the browser.
There are two settings that need to be set:

1. Cookies:
   In Chrome go to settings...click Advanced...click Content settings...click cookies..."keep local data only until you close your browser" should be turned ON.
2. System setting:
   In Chrome go to settings...click Advanced...scroll to system..."continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" should be turned OFF.

Both of these need to be set as indicated for this to work.

I am no expert but this has worked for me. I have closed the browser and it has required me to login to Google.

Comment: I asked for a timeout to sign out, not by closing the web browser.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know how or even if it’s possible to set a time out, but you can always sign out of all other sessions from the desktop version, by going to *Last account activity* (lower-right corner, under the emails list) → *Details* → *Sign out all other sessions*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex,I know about that feature from gmail, but that's not my question as that procedure is totally manual and I'm trying to overcome my  "memory leaks"